# Strapi registration works, but returns empty data object

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I'm trying to work on an Authentication flow using strapi. I set up the `/api/auth/local/register` endpoint, and it works -- if I register a user and then refresh the strapi Users page, the new user displays, the network tab shows the 200 OK for the request, but the problem is that I am trying to get a jwt token from the response data, and the data object is empty, and I can't seem to figure out why.

this is /pages/api/register.js on my frontend

```
export default async(req, res) => {
    const {username, password, email} = req.body

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.STRAPI_URL}/auth/local/register`, {
            username,
            email,
            password,
            confirmed: "true"
        }).then((res) => console.log('res', res))

        // setCookie({res}, 'jwt', response.data.jwt, {
        //     httpOnly: true,
        //     maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        //     path: '/'
        // })

        res.status(200).end()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send('api error', e)
    }
}
```

and the output of my `console.log(res)` is a long object with all the correct information about the request, but it ends with this:  `data: {}`

According to every tutorial / walkthrough I find, this data object is supposed to contain the User information, as well as a jwt token I can use. In my strapi settings, I have email confirmation turned off. The user is successfully registered and shows up in the database. So why is the data object returning nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Strapi v4.2.2 using Providers for Login.

I disabled one of my middlewares on `.../config/middlewares.js` and then it works.
This middleware called `flatten-response` was about removing the `data` and `attributes` keys from the response object given by strapi.

Source of the middleware: https://gist.github.com/hucancode/5b495aabf75fc3b940df3e5f94d5b927

So, maybe you can try to disable your middlewares to check wich one fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to publish your entries besides saving them